# How to parse to TDateTime a date time returned from a JSON String in Delphi XE 10

Tags: json, rest, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I receive the following JSON from a request:

```
{
  "cdPlayer": 3,
  "nmPlayer": "Player Name",
  "dtCreate": "2016-08-24T22:53:31.687",
  "dtChange": null,
  "idStatus": true
 }
```

I would like to load convert dtCreate and dtChange to TDateTime. How to properly do this? There is no `TJSONDateTime` to cast the `GetValue`. Below is my current code where I'm casting it to a plain String.

```
procedure TfrmPrincipal.btnInfoClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  jsonRoot: TJSONObject;
  tokenRequest: TRESTRequest;
  tokenResponse: TRESTResponse;
  tokenClient: TRESTClient;
  tokenAutenticacao: TOAuth2Authenticator;
begin
  tokenClient := TRESTClient.Create(nil);
  tokenRequest := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
  tokenResponse := TRESTResponse.Create(nil);
  tokenAutenticacao := TOAuth2Authenticator.Create(nil);
  try
    tokenRequest.Client := tokenClient;
    tokenRequest.Response := tokenResponse;
    tokenRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
    tokenClient.Authenticator := tokenAutenticacao;
    tokenAutenticacao.TokenType := TOAuth2TokenType.ttBEARER;
    tokenAutenticacao.AccessToken := 'token_string';
    tokenClient.BaseURL := 'http://host/url/method';
    tokenRequest.Execute;
    jsonRoot:= TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(tokenResponse.JSONText) as TJSONObject;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('cdPlayer => ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('cdPlayer').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('nmPlayer=> ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('nmPlayer').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('dtCreate=> ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('dtCreate').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('dtChange=> ' + jsonRoot.GetValue('dtChange').Value);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('idStatus=> ' + (jsonRoot.GetValue('idStatus') as TJSONBool).ToString);
  finally
    tokenAutenticacao.Free;
    tokenResponse.Free;
    tokenRequest.Free;
    tokenClient.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm using Delphi XE 10 Seatle. Thanks

**EDIT**

As far as the duplicate goes, I had no ideia that this Data format was ISO 8601. That's why I couldn't find the answer anywhere through Google. Maybe my question will help some others that, like me, didn't know as well.

Comment: I had no ideia this format was ISO 8601. That's why I could find the answer. But Tks

Comment: Indeed. Totally understand. Bottom line with date conversion is that almost certainly all questions eating to dates have already been asked. Somehow need to find them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would extract each part of the date (year, month, day, hours, minutes, milliseconds) from that string, and encode a datetime value. It's easy because each part is always at the same position.

```
function JSONDate_To_Datetime(JSONDate: string): TDatetime;
var Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond: Word;
begin
  Year        := StrToInt(Copy(JSONDate, 1, 4));
  Month       := StrToInt(Copy(JSONDate, 6, 2));
  Day         := StrToInt(Copy(JSONDate, 9, 2));
  Hour        := StrToInt(Copy(JSONDate, 12, 2));
  Minute      := StrToInt(Copy(JSONDate, 15, 2));
  Second      := StrToInt(Copy(JSONDate, 18, 2));
  Millisecond := Round(StrToFloat(Copy(JSONDate, 19, 4)));

  Result := EncodeDateTime(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, Millisecond);
end;
```

Comment: Yeah.. I thought about doing that. I just thought that would be a built-in function that did it, and treated the Time Zone as well.

Comment: As far as I know there is not an standard JSON date format, so it's not surprising that Delphi doesn't have a TJSONDateTime class.

Comment: I see. It is generated from .Net Web API. I`ll give it some time, to see if any other answer pops up. Thank you soo much for your time.

Comment: Marc, a slight correction on your code, just for posperity's sake, it's StrToFloat. :)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Worth to mention what "JSONDate" term is bogus because `Date`s are completely outside of JSON specification, unfortunately.

Comment: If seconds start at 18 and have 2 digits, milliseconds cannot start at 19. Also I cannot see why making the millliseconds a 0 or 1 value with the round, instead of just converting the integer value after the dot to the actual milliseconds.

Comment: Since Delphi XE6 the function System.DateUtils.ISO8601ToDate solves this. See also http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.DateUtils.ISO8601ToDate